# QGIS print composer and label with svg background error

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I have a problem with labels in QGIS. I'm using a background svg for some labels (street numbers). In QGIS, it's all ok but when I use the composer there is a bug (I suppose), because I see some strange artifacts.

[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzOp2wS_owhRM1hpSFFJXzlOa0E/view?usp=sharing)

[svg](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzOp2wS_owhRflJUZXNlekpMaHJzQ2VRWms3RHJRc19vOGFrNG9Idl8tU2haV1UtNkZjNlk&usp=sharing)

[image: Squares and elipse on the right are the artifacts]

If I disable the layer with the street numbers, or if I remove the svg background, the artifacts disappear. The problem is reproducible only with svg, if I use the rectancle or another option, I don't see any problems. 
The artifacts can be seen in the composer preview too.

Can someone confirm this problem?

Tested with QGIS 2.6.1 and 2.8.1 Nightly

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the artifacts?

Comment: there is... http://i.stack.imgur.com/Irqkn.jpg Can't you seen it? The artifacts are the big rectangle and ellipse in the image.

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and add the image link there, too?

Comment: Have you tried re-testing this for [QGIS 2.8.2](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)? I tested labels with a svg background and it seems fine (this was for a line vector layer on QGIS 2.8.2).

Comment: No, because I work with 2.6.1 but I'm quite sure the bug still persists because it's old and I haven't seen tickets about this.

Comment: The link to the image does not work.

Comment: Can you post a link to the svg file you use?

Comment: edited the post and added another link to the image and the link to the svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SVG files have issues. Try opening them in Inkscape and selecting View -> Zoom -> Drawing. There's polygons present WAY outside the document area. These are showing up in the composer map, causing the artefacts.

Comment: THANK YOU! I haven't notice them becouse they are outside the page. I still don't understand why I saw them only in the composer map and not in the qgis view but the problem seems to be solved.